# Dynamically loading JavaScript widget with data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Currently I have a widget which you insert somewhere on you page with the following

```
<script src='http://domain.com/public/jsonp/widget.js' data-id='LFKkv' data-width='240'></script>
```

I would like to load this dynamically after the page has loaded, I have tried jQuery `$.getScript` like below, which fails miserably:

```
$.getScript("http://domain.com/public/jsonp/widget.js' data-id='LFKkv' data-width='240'", function(data){ ... })
```

Because of the spaces on the URL between the data attributes I assume.

I could use ajax but I don't know how to pass data attributes via the jQuery ajax call? How do I dynamically load the above widget with data attributes intact?

**EDIT:**
Including the relevant parts of my widget script so you can see how my widget grabs the data attributes:

```
    <script>

    var scriptName = "widget.js";
    TGW = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

    var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var targetScripts = [];

    for (var i in allScripts) {
        var name = allScripts[i].src
        if(name && name.indexOf(scriptName) > 0)
            targetScripts.push(allScripts[i]);
    }

    scriptTag = targetScripts[targetScripts.length - 1];

    // Getting the data attributes here
    jScript = TGW(scriptTag);
    id = jScript.data("id");
    widget_width = jScript.data("width");
   </script>
```

Comment: `$("head").append("<script  data-id='LFKkv' data-width='240'><\/script>").prop("src", 'http://domain.com/public/jsonp/widget.js');`

Comment: @dandavis I'm afraid this doesn't do anything...

Comment: @superphonic Can include `js`  within `widget.js` where widget accesses `data-*` attributes of `script` element when loaded at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 I am not sure what you just said, sorry.

Comment: @superphonic Can portion of `widget.js` which accesses `data-*` attributes of `script` element appended to document ?

Comment: @guest271314 No, the widget needs to stay self contained as it is...

Comment: @superphonic How does widget access `data-*` attributes of script element ? Can `widget.js` be included at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 I have added the relevant parts of `widget.js` to the question.

Comment: So just to be clear you want to pass attributes from server in url. Correct? And not define them on client side.

Comment: the browser does not send any attribute along to `widget.js`, so "I dynamically load the above widget with data attributes" doesn't mean anything... these data attributes are being read client-side by `widget.js` once it has loaded I presume. so if the tag is already there, I guess it's too late since it is not asynchronous. what are you exactly trying to achieve? to modify these attributes before `widget.js` loads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try passing `options` object to an "init" function which loads `widget,js`, set `options` on widget at `success` callback of "init" function

```
TGW = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
function initWidget (options) {
  return TGW.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "script"
  })
  .then(function(script) {
    // if `TGW.widgetName()` requires several seconds to load,
    // try adding adding `setTimeout` or `.delay` to wait
    // until `TGW.widgetName` defined before returning `TGW.widgetName`
    return options && TGW.widgetName 
           ? TGW.widgetName(options) 
           : TGW.widgetName(/* defaults?, are `id`, `width` required? */);
  });
};

initWidget({"id":"LFKkv", "width":"240"})
.then(function(widget) {
  console.log(widget)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('<script/>').attr({
        'src': 'http://domain.com/public/jsonp/widget.js',
        'data-id': 'LFKkv',
        'data-width': '240'
    }).appendTo('body')
});
```

Comment: Ermm... I am the owner of the widget, and it does see the data attributes, that's how the widget is customised

Comment: @superphonic, how did it see the attributes? Not from the backend?

Comment: You simply place that script tag, with the attributes, in your page where you want the widget to be displayed. The widget uses jsonp for cross domain usage

Comment: @superphonic, when you do  <script src=""> a request is made to the server, but I dont think it sends parameters based off the attriburtes to the server, just a normal request depending on what is in src=""

Comment: I can 100% confirm that it does see the data attributes.

Comment: @superphonic, yes, but `data-id='LFKkv' data-width='240'` only have meaning on the client side.

Comment: @superphonic, how can you confirm it does see them? Is there variables in the back-end matching them?

Comment: Huh? The attributes are used by the widget script to customise the widget before displaying on the page. They are definitely needed.

Comment: @superphonic, I know they are needed. But where do you use them? In the server, do you check `data-id `and `data-width` or do you check/use them in the client side?

Comment: It's all client side, I'm loading a JavaScript file, there is no server side in this equation. For a simple example lets look at the data attribute `data-width`. In the widget script (that I created), it takes this attribute and outputs a `div` of the size specified. I have lots of ways to configure the output of the widget using the data attributes, they are definitely needed.

Comment: @superphonic, exactly, so why would you need to inlude them in $.getScript? Put the code that sets the size etc elsewhere

Comment: The widget JavaScript file is specifically looking for the data-attributes, how do you suggest I put them elsewhere? Other people use this widget by simply pasting in the script tag above and configuring it using the attributes. I was simply look for a way to also have it load dynamically if needed by the end user.

Comment: Thanks for this. But nothing seems to happen, the widget is not visible anywhere on the page?

Comment: @superphonic, sorry, try now

Comment: I had to replace `<script></script>` with `&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;` as it broke the JavaScript on the page otherwise, but it still doesn't show the widget anywhere unfortunately...

Comment: It would be helpful to post the error message you received, while trying to append the `script` tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref) }   loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Answer (score 1):

ok you should try this instead:

```
$.getScript("http://domain.com/public/jsonp/widget.js?data-id=LFKkv&data-width=240", function(data){ ... })
```

This is how you pass parameters in a url. You put `?` and then start putting `data=value&data2=value2` And it has to be properly html encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your widget in a function, and use an event listener?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var targetScripts = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < allScripts.length; i++) {
        var name = allScripts[i].src;
        if (name && name.indexOf(scriptName) > 0)
            targetScripts.push(allScripts[i]);
    }

    var scriptTag = targetScripts[targetScripts.length - 1];

    console.log( scriptTag.dataset.width );

});
```